# Wordpress Display Posts with pagination of particular three categories

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

Can anyone please help how to list the posts in wordpress of particular category id  for eg. consider (55,37,28) are the category id. 
I want to display it using pagination. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as arguments you can pass categories id to fetch posts from that category

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type'=>'post_type_name', 'cat' => '55,37,28');
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
} ?>


 //this will echo out the pagination

echo paginate_links( array(
                'base'    => get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '%_%',
                'format'  => ( ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) && ! $wp_query->is_search ) || ( is_home() && get_option( 'show_on_front' ) !== 'page' && ! get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) ) ? '?paged=%#%' : '&paged=%#%',
                // %#% will be replaced with page number
                'currennext' => get_query_var('pages'),
                'total'   => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                'prev_t'=>true,
                'prev_text'=> __('« Previous'),
                'next_text'=> __('Next »'),
            ) );
```

For paginate_links you can look into [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Comment: Thank you, 
$args = array('post_type'=>'post_type_name');
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
is itself is false

Comment: Post_type_name should be the name of post, like posts,portfolio or products. Try using posts for now. @Rupali Dubey